# JQuery keyup always fired after checked box checked then unchecked

Tags: jquery

When a user enters a postcode and checks useAbove the postcode is populated in the mailing postocode. If the useAbove is unchecked the mailing postcode is cleared.
Now I get a bug, if the user enters a postcode the mailing postcode is populated even although

```
($("#useAbove").attr("checked") == false
```

it should not hit

```
$('#txtPostcode').keyup(function (event)
```

Is there a way I can check that `($("#useAbove").attr("checked") = false` and `$('#txtPostcode').keyup(function (event))` is fired at the same time?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#useAbove").click(function () {
      //If checkbox checked
      if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
         var Postcode = $('#txtPostcode').val();
         var Address = $('#txtAddress').val();

         $('#txtMailingPostcode').val(Postcode);
         $('#txtAddress1').val(Address);

         //Change mailing postcode when text changed
         $('#txtPostcode').keyup(function (event) {
              $('#txtMailingPostcode').val($('#txtPostcode').val());
         });

     } else {
         $("#txtMailingPostcode").val("");
     }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<table id="Table" border="1">
  <tr>
      <td>txtAddress</td>
      <td>    
          <input id="txtAddress" type="text" />
      </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>Postcode</td>
      <td>    
          <input id="txtPostcode" type="text" />
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="useAbove" id="useAbove"/></td>
     <td>Use address above</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Address</td>
     <td>
         <input id="txtAddress1" type="text" />
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Mailing Postcode</td>
     <td>    
         <input id="txtMailingPostcode" type="text" value="" />
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

This is a small program that i am using before I put it into my main mvc application.

Comment: which version of Query are you using?

Comment: jquery-1.4.2 the version that comes with vs2011 as default.

Comment: could we get the html and full javascript?

Comment: Sorry posted wrong jquery version it is jquery-1.4.1.js

Comment: Added HTML the full javascipt is included.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
```

I think the problem is this line. Replace it with

```
if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
```

the selector is not equal to `true` in the boolean sense, but it returns a "truthy" value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.is(':checked')` or set a value to `<input type="checkbox" name="useAbove" id="useAbove"/>` and use `$(this).val() == 'YOUVALUEHERE'`